# onActivityResult in fragment doesn't update edittext

Tags: java, android, barcode

I have a sample barcode scanner app using [this](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) library.
onActivityResult does not update the textView nor editText.
I did some search around and noticed that this is a common problem.
onActivityResult i get my value that i pass through, i can log and toast the value but does not work on setText() method.

**Edit**: I'm using fragments.
 Fragment A is where the button, edit & textview are, Fragment B is the barcode scanner and i use popBackStack() to return to fragment A(received data from Fragment B);

Here is my code:

```
package com.gilbert.apptastic.barcodefragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static final int DIALOG_FRAGMENT = 1;
    public TextView textView;
    public TextView textView2;
    public TextView textView3;
    public TextView textView4;
    public EditText editText;
    public Button button;
    public String barcode;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        textView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        editText = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scanBarcode();
            }
        });
//        setText();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == DIALOG_FRAGMENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
//            System.out.println("ok");

            barcode = data.getExtras().getString("barcode");
//            edit_barcode.setText(value);
            setText();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), barcode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            System.out.println(barcode);
//            edit_barcode.setText(barcode);
        }
    }

    public  void setText() {
        System.out.println(barcode);
        textView.setText(barcode);
        textView2.setText(barcode);
        textView3.setText(barcode);
        textView4.setText(barcode);
        editText.setText(barcode);
    }

    public void scanBarcode(){

        Barcode barcode = new Barcode();
        barcode.setTargetFragment(PlaceholderFragment.this, DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, barcode);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("VIEW");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Barcode Class:

```
package com.gilbert.apptastic.barcodefragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.ZBarScannerView;

public class Barcode extends Fragment implements ZBarScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZBarScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mScannerView = new ZBarScannerView(getActivity());
        return mScannerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        if(!rawResult.getContents().isEmpty()){
        mScannerView.startCamera();
//        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("barcode", rawResult.getContents());
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        }else {
//            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            mScannerView.startCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }
}
```

my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="Barcode"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try creating a toast using barcode as string and see if the string is succesfully passed or not

Comment: @HirakChhatbar did that,and it  works fine

Comment: i have made an answer with possible solutions. plz have a check if ny of them helps

Comment: i would not trust `textView` to be still a valid reference. possibly you need to search for it again. I would try `((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(barcode)`;

Comment: @njzk2 i get "java.lang.NullPointerException" i use that

Comment: i think it may be because the `onActivityResult` happens before the fragment is displayed again. You possibly need to set the `barcode` value in `onResume`, to be sure the view is on the screen.

Comment: Do you get any error when you call setText() (trying to access the textviews) on onActivityResult?

Comment: Have you tried to implement onActivityResult on your MainActivity and update the TextViews/EditText from there? I think the problem is something related to what @njzk2 said.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks.
OnResume did the fix for me.

Comment: The OnResume solution should be an answer in this thread. I spent hours on this issue before finally reading through the comments and discovering the OnResume comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these

**1** ) Instead of

```
barcode = data.getExtras
```

try

```
barcode = data.getStringExtra("barcode")
```

**2**) Instead of initiating barcode

```
String barcode;
```

Try doing this in your onActivityResult,

```
String barcode = data.getExtras().getString("barcode");
```

**3** ) Instead of putting data directly into intent, use a bundle.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString ("barcode", rawResult.getContent());
Intent i = new intent();
i.putExtras (b);
```

In your onActivityResult

```
Bundle b = getIntent.getExtras();
String s = b.getString("barcode");
```

Then use s where you need it.

Comment: apparently the OP successfully retrieved the `barcode` content, so I don't think your answer is relevant.

Comment: the second options is worth giving a try. not only him, but many have been through this kind of problem where textview doesnt update in onActivityResult. so from my point of view, it is worth giving a try to every possible thing that can be done

Comment: thanks for the answer but i doesn't update textview ,but i get the date correct from fragment B. option 3 how do you pass a bundle on popBackStack()?

Comment: depends on what u r getting in rawResult.getContents(); is it a stirng or something?

Comment: @HirakChhatbar yes i get a string

Comment: @HirakChhatbar: but the `barcode` string is, according to the OP, correctly logged. Clearly the issue is not with passing the data from a fragment to the other.

Comment: @HirakChhatbar i check it, i get the data correct.
but does not update the textview. i think i has to do something textview.setText(). it does not run somehow. so passing data it a problem here.

Comment: i know that. i too had the same problem (option 2 in my answer solved my problem then) bt what else can be done in this case? lets have a look at his xml. @Gilbert92 plz post ur xml which has those textviews.

Comment: @HirakChhatbar added, even if i run this: "textView.setText("barcodasdasdsadsadasd0e");" it does not update

Comment: set textColor to black (if ur background is white) in all textviews in xml. may be u have used appearance attribut, so may be its color might be white

Comment: m glad to help. happy programming :D